# Does FindBugs Ant task require a JAR?

Tags: java, ant, jar, war, findbugs

The [FindBugs docs for Ant tasks](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/manual/anttask.html) are a little confusing. I have traditionally always used FindBugs via the Eclipse plugin, where you just select your project and click on "FindBugs" to get a report.

With the `findbugs` Ant task, there is a nested `<class>` element that is:

> A[n] optional nested element specifying which classes to analyze.

Based on the examples I see, it looks like FB actually requires you to first JAR your project before running the FB task on it.

Can someone confirm this and explain what the `class` element is? The description is pretty vague for a newcomer like myself to make sense of.

Second, and more important, is the fact that my project is actually a Java web app (WAR) file.

So, if I'm not mistaken, and if FB needs to have a JAR to conduct its analysis on, then my strategy would be to create a "temp JAR" of my project right inside the `<target name="findbugs">` target, and have it just be composed of all my compiled Java classes. This would not be executable and would just be fore satisfying FB and would be deleted as part of the later build.

Am I way off base here? What's the standard operating procedure for Java web app builders to use FB in their Ant builds? Thanks in advance!

Comment: For example of how to configure FB ANT task jars See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12744819/findbugs-issue-with-ant/12759178#12759178

Answer (score 0):

If you download FindBugs itself (in my case, version 2.0.1) and launch the gui from the included batch file, it restricts the file types you can put into a project for analysis: inside the "New Project" dialog, to "jar, war, ear, zip, sar". 
So, I guess, zipping your .class files will be enough - after all, a .jar is just a zip of your .class files in their folder structure, plus the manifest file added.

However, if you open a folder with non-zipped source files, FindBugs will attempt analysis nevertheless.

**[Update** I finally got the FindBugs ant task to work on my system. It definitely works on class files. 
It was quite some work to get it running, as there are some tricky issues that required reading the source code to resolve. E.g., it is tricky to include your own jars, e.g. for using log4j logging, some parameters that would help you are undocumented, and the minimum rank for a bug to be reported is quite high and cannot be lowered as far as I experienced. If you have any issues, please let me know, I'm glad to help.**]**

Comment: I am having an issue using findbugs with ANT. I am following this http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/manual/anttask.html but can't get to run.

Comment: can you please describe the steps u followed to get it run. thx

Comment: I'm very sorry, but after all thes years (having switched companies and all in the meantime), I can no longer access that code (nor that personal memory, for that matter) :(
If you specify your concrete Problem (+ outputs etc...) in detail, and make it another question on this site, I can have a look, though