# FindBugs refuses to find bcel jar on classpath

Tags: java, ant, findbugs

For the life of me, I am trying to get FindBugs (2.0.1) to run as part of my command-line Ant build. I downloaded the FindBugs JAR and extracted it to /home/myuser/java/repo/umd/findbugs/2.0.1/findbugs-2.0.1:

[image]

As you can see in the screenshot, under /home/myuser/java/repo/umd/findbugs/2.0.1/findbugs-2.0.1/lib there is a JAR called `bcel-1.0.jar`, and if you open it, you can see that I have drilled down to a class called `org.apache.bcel.classfile.ClassFormatException`. Hold that thought.

I then copied /home/myuser/java/repo/umd/findbugs/2.0.1/findbugs-2.0.1/lib/findbugs-ant.jar to ${env.ANT_HOME}/lib to make it accessible to the version of Ant that is ran from the command-line (instead of the Ant instance that comes built-into Eclipse).

My project directory structure is as follows:

```
/home/myuser/sandbox/workbench/eclipse/workspace/myapp/
    src/
        main/
            java/
        test/
            java/
    build/
        build.xml
        build.properties
    gen/
        bin/
            main/ --> where all main Java class files compiled to
            test/ --> where all test Java class files compiled to
        audits/
            qual/
        staging/
```

Inside `build.xml`:

```
<project name="myapp-build" basedir=".." default="package"
    xmlns:fb="antlib:edu.umd.cs.findbugs">

    <path id="findbugs.source.path">
        <fileset dir="src/main/java">
            <include name="**.*java"/>
        </fileset>
        <fileset dir="src/main/test">
            <include name="**.*java"/>
        </fileset>
    </path>

    <taskdef name="findbugs" classname="edu.umd.cs.findbugs.anttask.FindBugsTask"
        uri="antlib:edu.umd.cs.findbugs"/>

    <!-- Other Ant target omitted for brevity. -->

    <target name="run-findbugs">
        <!-- Create a temp JAR that FindBugs can use for analysis. -->
        <property name="fb.tmp.jar" value="gen/staging/${ant.project.name}-findbugs-temp.jar"/>
        <echo message="Creating ${fb.tmp.jar} for FindBugs."/>
        <jar destfile="gen/staging/${ant.project.name}-findbugs-temp.jar">
            <fileset dir="gen/bin/main" includes="**/*.class"/>
            <fileset dir="gen/bin/test" includes="**/*.class"/>
        </jar>

        <echo message="Conducting code quality tests with FindBugs."/>
        <fb:findbugs home="/home/myuser/java/repo/umd/findbugs/2.0.1/findbugs-2.0.1"
            output="html" outputFile="gen/audits/qual/findbugs.html" stylesheet="fancy-hist.xsl" failOnError="true">
            <sourcePath refid="findbugs.source.path"/>
            <class location="${fb.tmp.jar}"/>
        </fb:findbugs>
    </target>

    <target name="echoMsg" depends="run-findbugs">
        <echo message="The build is still alive!!!"/>
    </target>
</project>
```

But when I run `ant -buildfile build.xml echoMsg` from the command-line, I get an error in FindBugs:

```
run-findbugs:
    [echo] Creating gen/staging/myapp-build-findbugs-temp.jar for FindBugs.
    [jar] Building jar: /home/myuser/sandbox/workbench/eclipse/workspace/myapp/gen/staging/myapp-build-findbugs-temp.jar
    [echo] Conducting code quality tests with FindBugs.
[fb:findbugs] Executing findbugs from ant task
[fb:findbugs] Running FindBugs...
[fb:findbugs] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/bcel/classfile/ClassFormatException
[fb:findbugs] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.bcel.classfile.ClassFormatException
[fb:findbugs]   at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
[fb:findbugs]   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
[fb:findbugs]   at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
[fb:findbugs]   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
[fb:findbugs]   at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
[fb:findbugs]   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
[fb:findbugs] Could not find the main class: edu.umd.cs.findbugs.FindBugs2.  Program will exit.
[fb:findbugs] Java Result: 1
[fb:findbugs] Output saved to gen/audits/qual/findbugs.html

echoMsg:
    [echo] The build is still alive!!!
```

Here's what has me *amazed*:

- Even with `failOnError="true"`, FindBugs is not halting the build even when this runtime exception is encountered
- The last piece of output "`Output saved to gen/audits/qual/findbugs.html`" is a lie! There is *nothing* in `gen/audits/qual`!
- The `bcel-1.0.jar` is absolutely under FindBugs home, just like every other JAR in the lib/ directory.

**Please note**: the `findbugs-ant.jar` is definitely copied to ANT_HOME/lib; otherwise I would be getting a failed build complaining that it couldn't find the Ant tasks. As a sanity check, I went ahead and did this (I deleted the `findbugs-ant.jar` from ANT_HOME/lib and got a failed build). This build doesn't fail (it succeeds!). It just doesn't run findbugs.

Can anyone spot what is going on here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12744819/findbugs-issue-with-ant/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Funny thing because I am using the same version of Findbugs and the jar file is named `bcel.jar` not `bcel-1.0.jar`. I am also running Findbugs from an `Ant` script. As crazy as it might sound, try to download the Findbugs once again, unpack it in the place of your current one and run your script once again.

Answer (score 3):

You can debug where BCEL is being loaded from using the -verbose:class argument to the jvm.

To pass this argument to the jvm running findbugs, use the jvmargs flag on the find bugs plugin

> jvmargs
>
> Optional attribute. It specifies any arguments that should be
>   passed to the Java virtual machine used to run FindBugs. You may need
>   to use this attribute to specify flags to increase the amount of
>   memory the JVM may use if you are analyzing a very large program.

How did you populate the find bugs lib jar?  When I download findbugs.zip, I get a lib directory which looks very different than what you show.  In particular, mine contains a bcel with a version of 5.3, not 1.0 as you show.

Comment: Thanks @sbridges I'll check it out - and I'm using Ant 1.8.4

Comment: I think you have the wrong bcel version.  If I download findbugs 2.0.1.zip, the bcel it includes is 5.0.3

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you actually have BCEL in the classpath twice. And the file is being loaded from the jar outside the FindBugs library. Then, when FindBugs tries to load the jar, it finds the BCEL **in** the FindBugs library and cannot load it, because it's already loaded.

The solution would be to find where else BCEL exists in the classpath and remove it.

Comment: That's a great suggestion @Zagrev (+1) I'll give it a try in a few minutes here. Just out of curiosity, what made you suspect this to be the case? I only ask because I wouldn't have thought of it in 1,000 years, and it makes sense! (I've definitely added this JAR elsewhere recently...)

Comment: horrible, horrible experience :)

Comment: Well, it took a while, but I went through every single JAR file under `ANT_HOME/lib` as well as in my FindBugs home directory, and that `bcel-1.0.jar` is the *only* JAR containing that class. Any other ideas?? Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You might have to define a AuxClasspath to include the classpath that your `<javac>` task used when compiling your class files.

You don't show how the compile took place, so I am assuming your created a `compile.classapath` classpath reference:

```
<javac destdir="gen/bin/main"
   srcdir="src/main/java"
   classpathref="compile.classpath"/>

<fb:findbugs home="/home/myuser/java/repo/umd/findbugs/2.0.1/findbugs-2.0.1"
    output="html" outputFile="gen/audits/qual/findbugs.html" stylesheet="fancy-hist.xsl" failOnError="true">
    <auxClasspath refid="compile.classpath"/>
    <sourcePath refid="findbugs.source.path"/>
    <class location="${fb.tmp.jar}"/>
</fb:findbugs>
```

Comment: Thanks @David W. (+1) - added the `auxClasspath` and still the same error. I really feel like Zagrev might have been on to something with the duplicate JAR idea, but I can't seem to find it. I'm wondering, is there a tool out there that I could point my ANT_HOME/lib directory to, and have it print out a list of every Java class inside of every JAR in that directory? That way I could scan the output for duplicate BCEL classes.

Comment: @pnongrata _"s there a tool out there that I could point my ANT_HOME/lib directory to, and have it print out a list of every Java class inside of every JAR in that directory?"_ Take a look at [Tattle Tale from JBoss](http://www.jboss.org/tattletale).

Answer (score 1):

I don't see from your Ant script that bcel is landing on any classpath that the findbugs task would be able to load it from.  You might want to try making your taskdef explicitly include everything findbugs needs.

```
<taskdef name="findbugs" classname="edu.umd.cs.findbugs.anttask.FindBugsTask"
    uri="antlib:edu.umd.cs.findbugs">
  <classpath>
    <fileset dir="/home/java/repo/umd/findbugs/2.0.1/findbugs-2.0.1">
      <include name="*.jar"/>
    </fileset>
  </classpath>
</taskdef>
```

Answer (score 0):

most classpath problems you can debug with [tattle](http://www.jboss.org/tattletale/docs). it will report you all jars in your project. all duplicated classes etc. saved me a lot of time.

there is also ant task ready: http://docs.jboss.org/tattletale/userguide/1.2/en-US/html/ant.html